# How to forward pipe a value to the left side parameter of a function?

Tags: f#, f#-3.0

For example,

```
let fn x y = printfn "%i %i" x y
1 |> fn 2 // this is the same as fn 2 1 instead of fn 1 2
```

How to make it `fn 1 2`?

This is just a simplified example for test. I have a complex function return a value and I want to forward pipe it to the left side (in stead of right side) of a function.

Comment: The usual way to change the currying order would be to pipe into an anonymous function: |> fun x -> fn x 2

Comment: This might as well be a good indication that you should switch the order of parameters for the `fn` function (unless you have other pipes that need to pass the second argument).

Comment: I think Tomas is right--I think that's a smell that should be telling you that you might want to reorder the parameters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume that you have at least two pipes. Otherwise, `fn 1 2` does the job; why should we make it more complicated?

For *commutative* functions (which satisfy `f x y = f y x`) such as `(+)`, `(*)`, etc. you can just use `1 |> fn 2`.

For other functions, I can see a few alternatives:

1. Use backward pipes

   ```
   arg1
   |> fn1
   |> fn2 <| arg2
   ```

   I tend to use this with care since operators' precedence might cause some subtle bugs.
2. Use `flip` function

   ```
   let inline flip f x y = f y x

   Array.map2 (fun y d -> (y - d) ** 2.0) y d
   |> Array.sum
   |> flip (/) 2.0
   ```

   It's not pretty but it's clear that order of arguments in `(/)` is treated differently.
3. Use anonymous functions with `fun` and `function` keywords
   This is handy if you need pattern matching in place.

   ```
   input
   |> createOption
   |> function None -> 0 | Some _ -> 1
   ```

IMO, you don't have to pipe all the way. Create one more `let` binding, then your intention is clear and you can avoid bugs due to unusual styles.

```
let sum =
   Array.map2 (fun y d -> (y - d) ** 2.0) y d
   |> Array.sum
 sum / 2.0
```

Comment: +1 for "you don't have to pipe all the way" :-) as well as for all the other great alternatives.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution that looks pretty.  I don't know if it is too practical though

```
1 |> fn <| 2
```

Comment: I use this frequently for `defaultArg`.

Comment: How to use it with `defaultArg`, e.g. `a |> Array.tryHead |> defaultArg <| ""` - will give you the first string of the array or empty string if array is empty.